# Оптимизация кода подсчета вхождений

Tags: python, dict

Создаю из списка словарь с подсчетом вхождений. Можно ли этот код преобразовать в одну строку?

```
nums = [9,4,9,8,4,9]
ndict = {}

for i in nums:
    if i not in ndict:
        ndict[i] = 1
    else:
        ndict[i] += 1

print(ndict)
```

на выходе получаем:
{9: 3, 4: 2, 8: 1}

Comment: нет. но можно - `for i in nums: ndict[i] = ndict.get(i, 0) + 1`

Comment: А чем Counter из collections не устраивает?

Comment: наверное тем, что это учебное задание

Comment: в учебных целях можно написать Counter, например для дерева) знание стандартных либ - тоже очень хорошо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**вариант 1:**

```
ndict = {}

for i in nums:
    ndict[i] = ndict.get(i, 0) + 1
```

**вариант 2:**

```
ndict = {}

for i in nums:
    ndict[i] = ndict.setdefault(i, 0) + 1
```

**вариант 3:**

```
import collections

ndict = dict(collections.Counter(nums))
```

**вариант 4:**

```
ndict = dict().fromkeys(nums, 0)

for i in nums:
    ndict[i] += 1
```

**вариант 5:**

```
ndict = {}

for i in nums:
    ndict[i] = nums.count(i)
```

**вариант 5.1:**

```
ndict = {i: nums.count(i) for i in nums}
```

**вариант 5.2:**

```
ndict = {i: nums.count(i) for i in set(nums)}
```

**вариант 6:**

```
ndict = dict(zip(nums, map(nums.count, nums)))
```